# How to change quotation format in KOMA-Script Book

Tags: formatting, lyx, koma-script

Right now, my quotations look like this:
[image: Quotation with indent on first line]

The code is just: `\begin{quotation} ... \end{quotation}`

Is there any way to remove the indent from the first line and put a space between quotation paragraphs, instead? I've gotten rid of indents in the rest of my document, so I want to have the quotations conform to that look.

This is what I'm looking for *(this was a screenshot from a plain text editor and not the output of anything from LaTeX)*:

[image: Paragraphs spaced without indents]

I'm using KOMA-Script book class in the LyX editor. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't want `quotation`, you want `quote`.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Thank you, I switched which tag I used and the formatting looks fine now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments